# Using spritekit, how can you achieve a scrolling, randomly sloped floor in a side scrolling game?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I'm thinking of something akin to Ski safari, as seen the link below.
Creating a side scrolling effect with a static sprite is simple enough with SKActions, but if I wanted to use that same sprite (which is a rectangle) in random hills, would the sprite need to be transformed every frame to create new hills? If so, how can you transform sprites from within SpriteKit? I feel like when running on a mobile platform this would cause a large frame rate drop

If not, does that mean that you would have to create slopes yourself and program them in randomly?

For completeness sake, here is how I am generating a simple scrolling floor:

```
func makeBackground(){

var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "sprite-floor")

var shiftBackground = SKAction.moveByX(-backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 1.4)
var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
var movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground, replaceBackground]))

 for(var i: CGFloat = 0; i < 5; i++){
   let background=SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
   background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
   background.size.height = self.frame.height / 10
   background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * i), y: background.size.height)
   background.runAction(movingAndReplacingBackground)

   self.addChild(background)
 }
}
```

(for some reason the SO image uploader isn't working, so here is the link to my example:http://www.unwinnable.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Ski.jpg )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial might be able to help.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

It deals with replicating the level creation from Tiny Wings which had procedurally generated hills to land on. Should be a good starting place for you.